# Colouring shape text using cell formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet that I use for heatmapping, colouring in shapes based on cell values. I can change the background colour of the shape change based on the cell using:

```
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Range(Range("ColourCode").Value).Interior.Color
```

And if I can change the colour of the selected shape using:

```
Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.Characters.Font = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

But if I use the same Value approach as below, it doesn't change the text colour at all:

```
Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.Characters.Font.RGB = Range(Range("ColourCode").Value).Font.Color
```

Any ideas on what is wrong, or how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You should try it like this...

```
Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = Range("ColourCode").Font.Color
```

Comment: Thanks, this works to copy the font colour of the named cell however, that cell contains a VLOOKUP from an array which is why I'm using the value in the cell colour as below. Is this even possible for the font colour?~
    Range(Range("ColourCode").Value).Interior.Color

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but in that line of code, the right part should refer to the color of the font in the source range.

Comment: Managed to solve it, I had a bracketing issue, thanks for your help.

The code that worked in the end was:

         Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = Range(Range("ColourCode").Value).Font.Color

Comment: @JohnWalsby-Tickle You're welcome! Glad your issue has been resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to use the Font.Colors function.

```
Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Colors  = [RGB Value of whatever color you want]
```

It can be done to strings as a whole with the .Forecolor function in a similar way.